# Unable to make a soap call with multiple headers

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

for some reasons, I'm not sure why I'm getting an error on a two elemented SOAP call function:

Here's the sample XML:

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Header>
    <AuthenticationHeader xmlns="http://omscom/">
      <Username>devuser</Username>
      <Password>devpass</Password>
    </AuthenticationHeader>
    <DebugHeader xmlns="http://omscom/">
      <Debug>false</Debug>
    </DebugHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetShippingCharge xmlns="http://omscom/">
      <StartDate>2016-01-24T00:00:00</StartDate>
      <EndDate>2016-05-24T09:10:06</EndDate>
    </GetShippingCharge>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

When I created my PHP I'm getting this error:

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> ProMail.WebServices.PMInvalidLoginException: Exception of type 'ProMail.WebServices.PMInvalidLoginException' was thrown. at ProMail.WebServices.Authentication.AuthenticateWSUser(String username, String password, String webServiceName, PMSystemType systemType, String serverHttpHostName) at ProMail.WebServices.OMS.Order.authenticate(String webServiceName) at ProMail.WebServices.OMS.Order.GetShippingCharge(DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate) at ProMail.WebServices.OMS.OMS.GetShippingCharge(DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- in /home/ferdie22/public_html/soap/soaptest.php:48 Stack trace: #0 /home/ferdie22/public_html/soap/soaptest.php(48): SoapClient->__call('GetShippingChar...', Array) #1 /home/ferdie22/public_html/soap/soaptest.php(48): SoapClient->GetShippingCharge(Array) #2 {main} thrown in /home/

Here is my code"

```
$wsdl = 'http://xxxxx.veracore.com/pmomsws/oms.asmx?wsdl';
$auth = array(
    'Username'=>'xxxxxx',
    'Password'=>'xxxxxx'
    );
$StartDate ='2017-03-01T00:00:00';
$EndDate   ='2017-03-07T00:00:00';

$xml_array['StartDate'] = $StartDate;
$xml_array['EndDate'] = $EndDate;

$debug = array('Debug'=>'false');
$headerparams = array(
    'AuthenticationHeader' => $auth,
    'DebugHeader' =>$debug
);

$service = new SoapClient($wsdl);
$headers = array();
$headers[] = new SoapHeader('http://omscom/', 'AuthenticationHeader',   $auth);

$headers[] = new SoapHeader('http://omscom/', 'DebugHeader', $debug);
$service->__setSoapHeaders($headers);   

$service->GetShippingCharge($xml_array); 

print '<pre>';
var_dump($service);
print '</pre>';
```

TIA

Comment: Am I even making any sense here?

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this issue? I got the same error today lol

Comment: Any updates Ferdie or @NextDeveloper ? I'm getting the same error from this same SOAP endpoint. Same response happens if I leave off the DebugHeader. Is it actually a credentials issue, or is there something else going on here we can work around?

Comment: This problem went away for me by having the client create a new API password. This error is an invalid credentials error, and it appears re-setting the API password resolves it.